# Redirect with numbers in URL

Tags: .htaccess

I have a redirect like this

```
Redirect 301 /dir/dir/843-987 /new_page
```

but instead to redirect to "/new_page" it does "/new_page/843-987"
Why? And how to avoid this?

Comment: is that `843-987` range or just the static number?

Comment: not 100% sure ... but I think it is a static number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is how `Redirect` directive works as it appends current URI to target.

You should use more power `mod_rewrite` rules for finer control:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^dir/dir/843-987/?$ /new_page [L,NC,R=301]
```

Make sure to use a new browser to test the change or clear cache completely.

Comment: I get the same result.

Comment: get 500 now, so htaccess is on

Comment: ok make sure this is topmost rule and there is no other .htaccess in your system and you have to completely clear browser cache.

Comment: to put the line on top, right after "RewriteEngine on", was the key

Answer (score 1):

If `843-987` is a static term, you can use the following code:

```
RewriteRule ^dir/dir/843-987/?$ /new_page [L,NC,R=301]
```

If `843-987` is a range of number, you can use the following code:

```
RewriteRule ^dir/dir/(84[3-9]|8[5-9][0-9]|9[0-7][0-9]|98[0-7])/?$ /new_page [L,NC,R=301]
```

Breaking down for `843` to `987` range:

```
Parse Into Range:

843 - 849
850 - 899
900 - 979
980 - 987

Parse Into Block Regex:

84[3-9]
8[5-9][0-9]
9[0-7][0-9]
98[0-7]

Combining Into Regex Pattern:

(84[3-9]|8[5-9][0-9]|9[0-7][0-9]|98[0-7])
```